# Writing a makefile to install manual pages for a library

Tags: install, man, make

If I have a C library, let's say "apple", and "apple" contains functions "banana" and "carrot", how do I write the "install" line in the makefile so that "man banana" brings up the manual page for the "apple" library?

Answer (score 5):

Make the `banana.3` man page a symbolic link to the `apple.3` page:

```
install-man: apple.3
    install ... apple.3 $(mandir)/man3/apple.3
    ln -s apple.3 $(mandir)/man3/banana.3
    ln -s apple.3 $(mandir)/man3/carrot.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy banana.3 to /usr/share/man/man3/ or perhaps /usr/local/share/man/man3.  Details on which directory to use depend on your build system and your users' configurations.  You might want to consider Automake.

Comment: There is no manual page for banana, only for apple.